# Problem with Elasticsearch query - [range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, console, kibana

I am unable to figure out what is wrong with below query.

```
GET website/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-1d/d",
            "lt": "now/d"
            }
          },
          "match": {
            "aspnet-request-url.keyword": "abc.com/Default.aspx"
          }
        }
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Both `range` and `match` are working fine independently.

As per documentation, it says when merging more than one query we should use either `must` , `filter`, `must-not` under `bool` query.

Still it is giving `[range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [range] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

**It is clear from the above error, that the query is not properly formed. Please refer to this to know more about the structure of the [query and filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).**

You are missing some brackets, try out the below search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        },
        {                          <-- note this
          "match": {
            "aspnet-request-url.keyword": "abc.com/Default.aspx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Bhavya, Thanks for the quick response. Yes it is correct.